# Is a mean of 0 and sd of 0.5 acceptable scaling for a normal prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I have thus far been fitting a Cauchy prior (centred at 0; scale of 2.5) on my parameters, as recommended by Gelman et al. (2008). They recommend scaling variables (predictors, and in the case of a linear regression, outcomes as well) to a mean of 0 and sd of 0.5.

However, I would like to explore the effect on the Bayes Factor of using a different set of priors. Based on [this](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations), I decided to also try two other priors: normal distributions with a mean of 0 and sd of either one or ten.

My question is whether the scaling procedure I used for the Cauchy prior (i.e., mean of 0 and sd of 0.5) is appropriate for these priors as well?

Comment: The question does not make sense in a void, i.e. without a reference to the context in order to decide what is its scale. Nor does Gelman et al. recommendation. Experimenting with different priors is a good idea, which shows the impact of selecting different priors on the same dataset, even though the Bayes factor cannot be used to select a prior.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Xi'an. The predictor is dichotomous, and the outcome is either dichotomous as well (i.e., correct/incorrect) or continuous ranging from 300 to 3000 (i.e., reaction time data). Wondering if this is enough information?